# Math value from another datasets with row & column equal

Tags: r

The first dataset is like this:

[image: Major and letter grade]

, and The second dataset is like this:

[image: Specific Value]

I want to add a new column in the first dataset with the corresponding value appear in the second table, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `specificvalue[as.matrix(majorgrade)]` should do it. You can index using the row and column values as a matrix. To get a definite answer, you should post your images as text though, so others can work with the test data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I use specificvalue[as.matrix(majorgrade)], and it works!!! You are brilliant!!!

Comment: Possible generic duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920441/index-values-from-a-matrix-using-row-col-indicies and here's another one that is nearly identical that i've answered previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885368/writing-a-function-that-looks-for-element-in-a-matrix-based-on-values-of-columns/49888458